# cannot send to cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firebase cloud firestore in my flutter project

I want to send user name by this way

```dart
final DocumentReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('info');
@override
  void initState() {
    reference.setData({'name':widget.username});
    super.initState();
  }
```

but I always get this problem

is it because something I forgot or my code is right ?
Run window:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (19131): PlatformException(error, Firestore component is not present., null)
E/flutter (19131): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
E/flutter (19131): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:18)
E/flutter (19131): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19131): #2      DocumentReference.setData (file:///C:/Users/Khaled/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.9.0+2/lib/src/document_reference.dart:46:30)
E/flutter (19131): #3      _Mainpage.initState (package:family_store/mainpage/mainpage.dart:25:15)
E/flutter (19131): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3830:58)
E/flutter (19131): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (19131): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
E/flutter (19131): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (19131): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (19131): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (19131): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (19131): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
E/flutter (19131): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
E/flutter (19131): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
E/flutter (19131): #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
E/flutter (19131): #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (19131): #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (19131): #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (19131): #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
E/flutter (19131): #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (19131): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (19131): #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (19131): #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
E/flutter (19131): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
E/flutter (19131): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
E/flutter (19131): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
E/flutter (19131): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
E/flutter (19131): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
E/flutter (19131): #44     ComponentElement._fir`
```

Logcat window:

```
2019-02-17 19:26:09.995 26233-26233/kbaq.familystore E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore: Failed to handle method call
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Firestore component is not present.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:86)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.1:78)
        at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getFirestore(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:82)
        at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getDocumentReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:92)
        at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:512)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:200)
        at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:163)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
2019-02-17 19:26:10.579 4651-4651/? D/io_stats: !@   8,0 r 10125543 434553904 w 8205894 179383648 d 838308 76817324 f 2264196 2262971 iot 16398040 14934520 th 392016 0 0 pt 0 inp 0 0 740999.148
2019-02-17 19:26:10.652 26233-26345/kbaq.familystore E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
    PlatformException(error, Firestore component is not present., null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
    #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:292:18)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      DocumentReference.setData (file:///C:/Users/Khaled/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.9.0+2/lib/src/document_reference.dart:46:30)
    #3      _Mainpage.initState (package:family_store/mainpage/mainpage.dart:25:15)
    #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3830:58)
    #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
    #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
    #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
    #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
    #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
    #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
    #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
    #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
    #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
    #24     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #26     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4860:14)
    #27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #29     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
    #30     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
    #31     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
    #32     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
    #33     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
    #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #35     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
    #37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
    #38     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
    #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
    #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
    #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
    #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
    #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
    #44     ComponentElement._fir
```

`pubspec.yaml`

```
name: family_store
description: family store

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/Coffee.jpg
    - assets/Food.png
    - assets/Juices.jpg
    - assets/Sweets.jpg
    - assets/textback.png
    - assets/Divider.png
    - assets/Icon.png
    - assets/sectionback.png
    - btn_gplus.png
    - btn_mobile.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

`app/gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "kbaq.familystore"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`android/gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath ('com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0') {
            exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
        }

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried this solotion that minshond here [Flutter: Firestore component is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382246/flutter-firestore-component-is-not-present/54384620)

but didn't work

Comment: According to your logcat _Mainpage.initState (package:family_store/mainpage/mainpage.dart:25:15). You have issue in your initstate()  line 25.Try to decalre the firestore reference inside initState() and then try.

Comment: @Harshapulikollu Didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downgrading the cloud_firestore dependency? 
I've seen a couple posts on this subject very recently, all of which use cloud_firestore 9.0+2.

Comment: I tried  downgrad  cloud_firestore after your answers but didn't work

Comment: Unfortunate, I'll let you know if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function as like myFunc(){} and set the cloud data in this function. After that call the fuction in initstate(){}.

```
 final DocumentReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('info');

      _myFunc() async {
        reference.setData({'name':_userName.text}).whenComplete((){
          print('Data updated in Cloud.');
        });
      }

void initState() {
    _myFunc();
    super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue, but in my case I did not specify the cloud_firestore version. Instead, I left the field empty "cloud_firestore:  " as explained in the Official Flutter [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqJ_KjFzL9I). However, if you do not specify the version number, it seems that the latest one is downloaded.  Yet, it seems that the latest version is not compatible with AndroidX and downgrading does not work.

I solved this issue by creating a new Flutter project in Android Studio and enabling Kotlin and Swift compatibility at the initial project configuration screen.

Then in the pubspec.yaml, I typed in this code:

```
dependencies:

  firebase_core: 0.2.5+1
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
```

Moreover, it seems that your pubspec.yaml does not have the firebase_core dependency.

This is my app's build gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.organization.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
//The following line must be placed at the end of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my project's build grade:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I understand that this solution may not be the most efficient one.  Specially, considering that you might have to create a new Flutter project. Nevertheless, once the new project is created as mentioned above, you can copy your old Flutter dart files into the new one.

Hopefully this can help you.