# How to find compatible pair of google-services and gradle version for react native project

Tags: java, android, react-native, flutter, gradle

Recently I've had to upgrade gradle versions of my react native projects.
Following are the files I currently have.
`android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
 dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
        // Add the following line:
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'  // Google Services 
    }
```

I'm now receiving error stating `Firebase Messaging component is not present`.
Upon searching the cause,I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969917/how-to-fix-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-error/62969918#62969918) that `gradle:3.5.4` and `google-services:4.3.10` are not compatible and I might have to downgrade the gradle version.

However on downgrading `gradle` to `3.4.x`, I get another error stating

```
> Android resource linking failed
  /home/thecodeninja/Desktop/FindUtsav/app/FindUtsav eject/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:36: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

and as it turns out, the reason for this error is that lower versions of gradle dont support  `<queries>` tag [[mentioned here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382246/flutter-firestore-component-is-not-present).

and so I`m completely stumped - **how do I find the right pair of gradle and google-services versions**